# Magento 2: How to move product info media block to my custom tab on product page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout, layout-update

How can I move **Product.info.media** block to my custom created tab on product view page in Magento 2.

My custom tab code is:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="specs.tab" as="specification" template="Magento_Catalog::product/related-products.phtml" group="detailed_info">
    <arguments>
        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Specification</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your **catalog_product_view.xml** file, and add the following code as a child of the `<body>` tag :

```
<move element="product.info.media" destination="specs.tab" as="product.info.media" />
```

This will move the block into your block, meaning the product.info.media is now a child of your block. Blocks can render their children from their templates. So you will need to add the following code to your template file which according to your code is **Magento_Catalog::product/related-products.phtml** :

```
<?= $block->getChildHtml('product.info.media') ?>
```